# BIND DNS server (Windows) - Unable to access my local domain from other computers on LAN

Tags: windows-7, router, dns, lan, bind

I have a BIND DNS server running on my Windows 7 development machine and I'm serving pages with WAMPSERVER.

My ideia is to develop some tools (in PHP) for my intranet at work and I want them to be accessible via LAN in this format:
`http://tools.mycompany.com`

I've already placed BIND and I can access `http://tools.mycompany.com` on the machine that holds BIND server, but **I cannot access it from other LAN computers**.

I've done the following on my router:

- defined static IP's for all LAN computers
- set Port Forwarding to my server (remember: it serves DNS and Web pages)
- set DNS server configuration to point to my LAN server

On LAN computers, I went to Local Area Network properties and also changed the DNS server IP in order to point to my local DNS server.

If it helps, here is my `named.conf` file:

```
options {
  directory "c:\windows\SysWOW64\dns\etc";
  forwarders {127.0.0.1; 8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4;};
  pid-file "run\named.pid";
  allow-transfer { none; };
  recursion no;
};

logging{
  channel my_log{
    file "log\named.log" versions 3 size 2m;
    severity info;
    print-time yes;
    print-severity yes;
    print-category yes;
  };
  category default{
    my_log;
  };
};

zone "mycompany.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "zones\db.mycompany.com.txt";
    allow-transfer { none; };
};

key "rndc-key" {
        algorithm hmac-md5;
        secret "qfApxn0NxXiaacFHpI86Rg==";
};

controls {
        inet 127.0.0.1 port 953
            allow { 127.0.0.1; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
};
```

...and a single zone I've defined - file `db.mycompany.com.txt`:

```
$TTL 6h
@   IN SOA  tools.mycompany.com.    hostmaster.mycompany.com. (
            2014042601
            10800
            3600
            604800
            86400 )

@       NS  tools.mycompany.com.

tools IN A 192.168.1.4
www IN A 192.168.1.4
```

On the file above `192.168.1.4` is the IP of the local machine inside my LAN.

Can someone help me here?
I need my web pages to be accessible from other computers inside my LAN using my custom domain name.

I've tried on other computers and they can access my server via `http://192.168.1.4/`, but no able when using `http://tools.mycompany.com` .

Please, consider the following:

I'm completely new to BIND

I have basic knowledge in Apache configuration

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Hi everyone, I left the project where I had this issue. So I don't know which answer solved this specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

you must add this line to the options in your `named.conf` file:

```
allow-query     { localhost; any; };
```

so the options will be like this:

```
options {
directory "c:\windows\SysWOW64\dns\etc";
forwarders {127.0.0.1; 8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4;};
pid-file "run\named.pid";
allow-transfer { none; };
recursion no;
allow-query     { localhost; any; };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. In my case it was due to port blocking by windows firewall.
DNS server runs on port 53, which is blocked by default in Windows 7.

I added rule for allowing port 53 on machine where BIND is installed.
For doing this,

1. Open command prompt in administrative mode.
2. Execute >**netsh firewall add portopening ALL 53 DNS-server**

That's it, now your domain should rock!